# Click mouse and draw fixed rectangle at mouse position in Video (python_opencv)

Tags: python, video, opencv

So during my webcam/video I would like to when I click my mouse, a rectangle is drawn at the mouse position, and the rectangle size is fixed ex. 80 X 80. In my current code, the rectangle follows the mouse but the size is always different. I want a fixed size exactly at the mouse position when I Click on a frame in the video.

Here is my code.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2 
from PIL import Image
import re



print('kaishi')
flag=0
drawing = False

point1 = ()
point2 = ()
ref_point = []
xvalues=[];
yvalues=[];
ref_point = []


cx=0;
cy=0;
 def mouse_drawing(event, x, y, flags, params):
     global point1, point2, 
     drawing,ref_point2,flag,refPt,cropping,cx,cy



     if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

        drawing = True
        point1 = (x, y)
        xvalues.append(x)
        yvalues.append(y)
        cx =x;
        cy=y;


elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    if drawing is True:
        point2 = (x, y)




elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        flag+=1;
        print('finished square')





cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("Frame")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Frame", mouse_drawing)


while True:
   _, frame = cap.read()

      if point1 and point2 :
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(200,cy),(cx,128),(0,0,255),0)
        print(cx,cy)

        flag=0;





    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

key = cv2.waitKey(25)
if key== 13:

    print('done')




elif key == 27:
     break



 cap.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you fixed a point of the rectangle and the other point follows the mouse. In your code it would be here:

```
cv2.rectangle(frame,(200,cy),(cx,128),(0,0,255),0)
```

Now, it will depend how the rectangle will be, is the point where you click the top left point? if it is then it should be something like:

```
cv2.rectangle(frame,(cx,cy),(cx + 80, cy +80),(0,0,255),0)
```

This example will be for a 80 x 80 rectangle.... In your code this will happen when you click.

However, your code has a lot of unused code... I would do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 

drawing = False
point = (0,0)

def mouse_drawing(event, x, y, flags, params):
     global point, drawing
     if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        point= (x, y)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow("Frame")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Frame", mouse_drawing)

while True:
   _, frame = cap.read()
   if drawing :
      cv2.rectangle(frame,point,(point[0]+80, point[1]+80),(0,0,255),0)

   cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
   key = cv2.waitKey(25)
   if key== 13:    
     print('done')
   elif key == 27:
     break

 cap.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you want the rectangle to follow your mouse after you clicked and to stop following after you release the button, change in the code I supplied before the `mouse_drawing` function like this:

```
def mouse_drawing(event, x, y, flags, params):
     global point, drawing
     if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        point = (x, y)
     elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
       if drawing is True:
        point = (x, y)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        point = (x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now the next thing I have to do is get the roi of the frame inside the rectangle.

Comment: @user3352739 sure, just make a new question about it :) with more details of what you want to achieve